# Probability of a five-card poker hand containing 2 pairs

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, poker

I am trying to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528964/probability-that-a-five-card-poker-hand-contains-two-pairs) question in my own way. I tried counting like this-
First card can be chosen in 52 ways, second in 3 ways because it has to be of same kind as first, third in 48 ways, fourth in 3 ways and fifth in 44 ways.
I got the answer as :
`(52*3*48*3*44)/5!` as the favorable events.
I was trying to solve it like the way it is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1540949)
Can anyone help me get it correct because I am not getting the correct answer this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're dividing by 5! because that's how many times you're overcounting each combination. However this isn't the right amount. Each hand $\{A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2, C\}$ is counted in $2 \times 2 \times 2 = 8$ different ways by your method since the first pair can be in any order, the second pair can be in any order and the order of the pairs can be swapped. This gives
$$ \frac{52 \times 3 \times 48 \times 3 \times 44}{2 \times 2 \times 2} = 123552$$
hands which are 2 pairs. This agrees with the frequency on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability#Frequency_of_5-card_poker_hands

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. Can you please elaborate a little more on the 2x2x2 part in the denominator, i didn't completely understand it. if {A1,A2} is one pair, then it can be in two ways i.e. {A1,A2} and {A2,A1}, for the order of pairs can be swapped part aren't there more than 2 permutations for the 2 pairs and  a single card?

Comment: No, there are not more than two permutations for the position of the two pairs and the single card. The way you count the cards means you start with a pair, then see another pair, then the single card comes at the end. The only thing you can do is to switch the two pairs or switch the order within each pair.

Comment: if X is pair 1, Y is pair 2 and Z is the single card then {X,Y,Z},{X,Z,Y},{Z,X,Y},{Y,X,Z},{Y,Z,X} aren't these permutations correct?

Comment: But your method only counts the ordering $(X, Y, Z)$ and $(Y, X, Z)$. Your method means that the first two cards are a pair, the third and fourth card is a different pair, and the fifth card is a singleton. You don't count any other orderings.

Comment: i am referring to the order of pairs can be swapped part only,  in the above comment. i agree with the ordering in the pair itself can happen in two ways, i am confused how the ordering between 2 pairs and a single card is just 2 ways.

Comment: Because that's how your method of counting works. You allow the first card to be any card (53 possibilities). You enforce the second card being a pair with the first one (3 possibilities). You enforce the third card being a different value from the first two (48 possibilities). You enforce the fourth card being a pair with the third card (3 possibilities). You enforce the fifth card being a different value from the first four (44 possibilities). This means that the last card is always the singleton. The ordering between the 2 pairs and the single card will always be (pair, pair, single card).

Comment: Oh now i think i understand,the way we are counting has fixed the singleton in 3rd position. Thank you for your time and patience :)

Answer (score 3):

If you start with the pairs, you're going to run into trouble since at some point you have to divide by multiple $2$s to account for swapping cards within pairs, as well as swapping the pairs. Rather, you should start with the kicker, and also fix one property at a time and not one *card* at a time:

- $13$ ways to select the rank of the kicker, $4$ choices for its suit
- $\frac{12×11}2$ ways to select the ranks of the two pairs
- $\frac{4×3}2×\frac{4×3}2$ ways to select the suits of each pair